# Evaluate a list

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, evaluation

I have a function $f(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ that takes $n$ arguments, and I would like to evaluate it using a list of lists $\lbrace\lbrace x_1,\cdots,x_n \rbrace,\cdots,\lbrace x_1',\cdots,x_n' \rbrace,\cdots \rbrace $.
The problem is that when I define

```
func[a_,b_,c_}:=a^2+b^2+c^2;
list={{1,2,3},{3,4,5},{6,7,8}};
```

I can't do

```
Table[funct[list[[i]]],{i,1,3}]
```

Because mathematica reads $f(\lbrace x_1,\cdots,x_n\rbrace)$ instead of $f(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$...

Comment: There's a typo: `func[a_,b_,c_}` should be `func[a_,b_,c_]` to begin with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say that `func[{1,2,3}]` doesn't work, but in Mathematica we can actually define such functions. We just have to write

```
func[{a_, b_, c_}] := a^2 + b^2 + c^2;
```

and boom, now it works. Now you can do

```
func /@ list
```

or

```
func@Transpose@list
```

The latter works because of something called "listability". You can also use that with your original definition of `func`, using `Apply` like so: `func@@Transpose@list`, but there is no advantage to using `Apply` in this manner rather than the way in which Szalbocs used it.

By the way `Map` or `/@` as it is also written is what you should be using instead of `Table[var[[i]],{i,...}]`. To begin with you can think of it as the equivalent of that, but with a simpler syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html).  The following will work:

```
func @@@ list
```

Example:

```
In[1]:= f @@ {1, 2, 3}
Out[1]= f[1, 2, 3]

In[2]:= f @@@ {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}
Out[2]= {f[1, 2, 3], f[4, 5, 6]}
```